# How can I malloc an array of struct to do the following using file operation?

Tags: c, arrays, file-io, struct, malloc

How can malloc an array of struct to do the following using file operation?
the file is .txt
input in the file is like:

```
10
22 3.3
33 4.4
```

I want to read the first line from the file and then I want to malloc an array of input structures **equal to the number of lines to be read in from the file. Then I want to read in the data from the file and into the array of structures malloc.** Later on I want to store the size of the array into the input variable size. return an array.After this I want to create another function that print out the data in the input variable in the same form like input file and suppose a function call clean_data  will free the malloc memory at the end.

I have tried something like:

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct input
{
    int a;
    float b,c;

}

struct input* readData(char *filename,int *size);

int main()
{


return 0;
}

struct input* readData(char *filename,int *size)
{
    char filename[] = "input.txt";
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    int num;
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        fscanf(fp,"%f", &num);
                struct input *arr = (struct input*)malloc(sizeof(struct input));

    }

}
```

Comment: Is the file a text file, or are you going to store the binary images of the struct values in the file?

Comment: take a look at realloc() if it needs to be an array

Comment: That's good, so what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I want to malloc an array of input structures equal to the number of lines to be read in from the file. Then I want to read in the data from the file and into the array of structures malloc. But I am not getting how to do this?

Comment: The file format seems to be crafted deliberately to avoid problems with `malloc`: the first number in the file specifies how many structures to allocate! `fscanf(fp, "%d", &number); arr = malloc(number * sizeof(*arr));` - or did I misunderstand?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a stucture to store both your input table and your table size:

```
typedef struct{
    int a, b;
    float c,d;
}Input;

typedef struct myInputs{
    uint size;
    Input* inputs;
}Input_table;
```

create functions to write or read an input in your file:

```
void addInput(Input_table* pTable, Input* pInput)
{
    pTable->inputs[pTable->size] = (Input*)malloc(sizeof(Input));
    memcpy((*pTable)->inputs[pTable->size], pInput); 
    pTable->size++;
}

Input* readInput(Input_table* pTable, uint index)
{
    if (pTable->size > index)
    {
        return pTable->inputs[index];
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

your read function becomes:

```
InputTable* readData(char *filename, int *size)
{
    Input_table myTable;
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    int num;
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        Input newInput;
        fscanf( fp,"%d;%d;%f%f", &(newInput.a), &(newInput.b), &(newInput.c), &(newInput.d));
        addInput( &myTable, &newInput);
    }
}
// Here your table is filled in
printf("table size:%d", myTable.size);
```

}

Comment: It's best to avoid the `_t` suffix, it's reserved by POSIX.

Comment: I removed them, but which convention would you use to declare custom types?

Answer (score 0):

To do what you're looking for is very expensive, as you would have to read through the entire file multiple times. Instead, consider making a dynamic array of structs that you can resize when you run out of room.

```
    struct data_t {
            int nval;               /* current number of values in array */
            int max;                /* allocated number of vlaues */
            char **words;           /* the data array */
    };

    enum {INIT = 1, GROW = 2};

    ...
    while (fgets(buf, LEN, stdin)) {
            if (data->words == NULL)
                    data->words = malloc(sizeof(char *));
            else if (data->nval > data->max) {
                    data->words = realloc(data->words, GROW * data->max *sizeof(char *));
                    data->max = GROW * data->max;
            }
            z = strtok(buf, "\n");
            *(data->words + i) = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(z) + 1));
            strcpy(*(data->words + i), z);
            i++;
            data->nval++;           
    }
    data->nval--;
```

While this isn't exactly the code you need, it's so close that adapting it to your problem should be easy to do. Instead of fgets(,,stdin), you would use fgets(,,fp), and instead of a char** inside of struct data_t, you could just put a struct input* with all of the mallocs and reallocs making appropriate changes for the size of your struct.

The struct data_t, of course, is just a header for the array of structs that you want to have, a place for putting your array and for keeping track of how many you have, and how much space you currently have allocated.